# Как в Python получить путь к исполняемому файлу

Tags: python, windows

Например, в компилируемых приложениях можно узнать расположение exe. Как получить путь к py файлу? Решение должно быть совместимо с Windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from os.path import abspath

print(abspath(__file__))
```